# how to filter item where lookup column null from custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to get items from custom list using REST API which lookup column is null.

how can i make filter query for this.?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the REST API response, Lookup column looks like following

```
{Internal Name of the column} + Id
```

Let's say lookup column name is `Person`, so it will `PersonId` in response. Now you can apply filter on `PersonId` column.

```
var query = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$filter=PersonId eq null";
```

To know more about `$filter`, you can follow my article

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)